# How to map network drives with multiple credentials per file server?

Tags: linux, windows, network-shares, smb

**How can I map multiple network drives on a single Windows host using more than one set of credentials?**

File server `jeeves` has two shares, `\\jeeves\alice` and `\\jeeves\bob`, requiring different credentials (Alice's and Bob's passwords).
The Windows host `winnie` needs to mount them both, via "map network drive."  Sadly, Windows doesn't support multiple credentials per file server.

So I introduce an Ubuntu host, `wooster`, which mounts `\\jeeves\bob` and then exports that directory that as `\\wooster\bob`.

Then `winnie` mounts `\\jeeves\alice` (as before) and `\\wooster\bob` (new).  Because `jeeves` and `wooster` are different servers, `winnie` can now use different credentials for these two.

Unfortunately, `winnie`'s **Windows Explorer does not recognize subdirectories** within `\\wooster\bob`!  They're shown only as files.  Other programs (DOS shell, PhotoShop, etc) navigate these sub-directories fine, but not the most fundamental file browser.  (DOS `dir` omits the flag `<DIR>` on sub-directories, although `cd` works;  `tree` doesn't.)  That makes the clever "wooster" trick not very useful.  *File* permissions on `jeeves` and `wooster` are sufficiently open, obviously.

In `wooster`'s `/etc/samba/smb.conf`, the share definition for `\\wooster\bob` is

```
[bob]
  path = /whatever
  browseable = yes
  valid users = bob
  read only = no
  comment = passthrough to Windows
  public = no
  printable = no
```

- Can this "wooster" trick be made to work?
- If not, is there another workaround to let the Windows machine `winnie` see both Alice's and Bob's files at once?

Comment: Why not just give Winnie proper access to Bob and Alice's folders (that way only Winnie's credentials are needed)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Winnie's" credentials, but Bob and Alice are separate users who may not be merged.  Just take that as given.  (This limitation of Windows has been whined about for over a decade.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Windows you can map multiple network drives using different credentials simply by providing a different hostname for each mapped drive.

Assume `Server1` has the IP address `192.168.1.10`. You want to map drive **F:** using **UserA**'s credentials and drive **G:** using **UserB**'s.  You run this command:

```
net use F: \\Server1\UserA /User:UserA PasswordA
net use G: \\192.168.1.10\UserB /User:UserB PasswordB
```

To use more than two sets of credentials you simply need to create additional host names for the remote server.  Two ways to create alias names are:

1. **Local hosts file**.  Edit your local `hosts` file to map an additional name to the remote server's IP address.  For example, on Windows with administrator privileges edit `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` and add the line `192.168.1.10 Server1`.
2. **DNS Record**.  If you have control over your DNS server you can create a record that maps an alternate name to the remote server's IP address.

Comment: Does that work with typographically distinct ways of typing the IP address, e.g., `192.168.1.012`?

Comment: Of course, if `Server1` happens to have more than one NIC, then it can have multiple IP addresses.

Comment: @G-Man Mapping with a zero-padded IP address didn't work because Windows interpreted it as an octal number as described in this [MSKB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/115388).

Comment: @Twisty: Well, I expected that; that's why I replaced the decimal `10` in the fourth octet with an octal `012`.  Also, `192.168.1.0xA` and `192.168.266` would work.  This is [defined by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/inet_addr.html), but [the IETF considers it non-standard](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-main-ipaddr-text-rep-02#section-2).

Comment: @G-Man Doh! I totally missed that! In my defense I was working with a completely different subnetwork so I didn't look closely at your example IP. I'll give it another shot armed with this enlightenment.